# comparing two files and giving an output which ever file has the highest count

Tags: java

The problem with my code is, sometimes it reads and compares the string without any issue but again it also throws errors when comparing other strings. I think my comparing function isn't performing enough to the mark, where do I need to set the code efficiently so that my comparison function works efficiently?

can someone please suggest to me something? so far I have tried comparing two files using bufferedreader. my code works to some extent but at the same time encounters an error

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:"

I have a few pictures which describe my problem intuitively. I think my **findtarget** function isn't accurate enough which is why it keeps throwing these exceptions

> *[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe8Rd.jpg) : click here to view the image.*
>
> *[NO-ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT7AR.jpg) : click here to view the image.*

and here is my two files which contains positive and negative keywords.

> *[NEGITIVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSo48.jpg) : file extention is negi.txt*
>
> *[POSITIVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUvFJ.jpg) : file extention is posi.txt*

here is the findtarget function which is used to compare the strings.

```
public static int findTarget(String target, String source) 
{

    int target_len = target.length();
    int source_len = source.length();

    int add = 0;

    // this function check the character whether it is present.       
    for (int i = 0; i < source_len; ++i) // i is a varialbe used to count upto source_len.
    {

        int j = 0; // take another variable to count loops
        //int[] k = new int[100];

        while (add == 0) 
        {
            if (j >= target_len) // count upto target length
            {
                break;
            } 
            else if (target.charAt(j) != source.charAt(i + j)) 
            {
                break;
            } 
            else 
            {
                ++j;
                if (j == target_len) 
                {
                    add++; // this will return 1: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return add;
    //System.out.println(""+add);
}
```

here is my entire code just incase if you wanna run them.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class test {
    public static int findTarget(String target, String source) 
    {

        int target_len = target.length();
        int source_len = source.length();

        int add = 0;

        // this function check the character whether it is present.       
        for (int i = 0; i < source_len; ++i) // i is a varialbe used to count upto source_len.
        {

            int j = 0; // take another variable to count loops
            //int[] k = new int[100];

            while (add == 0) 
            {
                if (j >= target_len) // count upto target length
                {
                    break;
                } 
                else if (target.charAt(j) != source.charAt(i + j)) 
                {
                    break;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ++j;
                    if (j == target_len) 
                    {
                        add++; // this will return 1: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return add;
        //System.out.println(""+add);

    }



public static void main(String... args) 
{
// function 1
        //this variable can be called from any place inside this main function.
        int testing1 = 0; 
        int testing2 = 0;
        try {

            //reads user review and store them inside source1
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter your review: ");
            String source1 = sc.nextLine();

            //establising a file object
            File file = new File("posi.txt");
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            //establising a file object
            File file2 = new File("negi.txt");
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

            String target1; // using a string variable to read the content of the file posi.txt

            while ((target1 = br1.readLine()) != null) //as long the condition is not null it will keep printing.
            {      
                testing1 += test.findTarget(target1, source1); // supplying two arguments to findtarget function.
            }

            String target2; // using a string variable to read the content of the file negi.txt

            while ((target2 = br2.readLine()) != null) //as long the condition is not null it will keep printing.
            {                           
                testing2 += test.findTarget(target2, source1); // supplying two arguments to findtarget function.
            }
            br1.close(); br2.close();
            System.out.println("positive is:"+testing1 +"\nnegative is :"+testing2); //-not going to print now! :D-
            System.out.println("\nthank you for your feedback! :)");

            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
            System.out.println("file error!");
            }


            // this function is an area where it stores the return value inside a file called pos.txt
            try 
            {  
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("pos.txt",true); 
            // using the true condition makes the line move to the next line.

            myWriter.write(" "+testing1);
            myWriter.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");      
            }

            // writing neg inside a file called neg.txt
            try 
            {        
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("neg.txt",true); 
            // using the true condition makes the line move to the next line.

            myWriter.write(" "+testing2);
            myWriter.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");      
            }

        // to evaluate an output based on highest count.
        if(testing1 > testing2)
            System.out.println("it is positive");
        else if (testing1 == testing2)
            System.out.println("it is neutral");
        else
            System.out.println("it is negative"); 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `i` to the lenght of `source` but you call

```
.
.
.
    else if (target.charAt(j) != source.charAt(i + j))
.
.
.
```

which exceeds the lenght of source at some point.

Lets say `i == source.length`, then `source.charAt(i + j)` throws an exception as soon as `j > 0`.

Comment: how do I overcome this problem? could you provide a sample code?

Comment: I showed you the problem with your code. You will have to think about the whole algorithm to avoid these exceptions. I am sure you can do this.

Comment: `for (int i = 0;i <= source_len - 1;i++) 
        {
           if (sourcee.regionMatches(i, targett, 0, target_len)) 
           {
              foundIt++;
              //System.out.println(sourcee.substring(i, i + target_len));
              break;
           }
        }
        if (foundIt == 0)
        {            
        }`

Comment: Did you fix it with my hint?

Comment: somehow I did. it works I use regionmatches method.

Answer (score 1):

finally, I was able to solve the problem by using one of **string method** known as **"regionmatches"**. Note: make sure your positive and negative files are arranged in an alphabetical sequence. This will give you an accurate increment.

*[Github](https://gist.github.com/tenchi12/7c19aea515ddc3fc8a41d2f092477f7e) : use my link to download the positive and negative keywords.*

```
public static int findTarget(String target, String source) //method/function
    {   
       String sourcee = source;
       String targett = target;

        int source_len = sourcee.length(); 
        int target_len = targett.length();     
        /* 
        **this function check the character whether it is present using one of string methond called "regionmatch"
        **regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset,int len)
        */       
        int add = 0;       
        boolean foundIt = false;    
        for (int i = 0;i <= source_len - 1;i++) 
        {
           if (sourcee.regionMatches(i, targett, 0, target_len))
           {
              foundIt = true;
              break;
           }
        }      
        //checking 
        if(!foundIt)
        {
            // do nothing.
        }
        else
        {
            add++;
        }  
        return add; //returns incrementation
    }
```